# Pandas merge is not giving the expected result

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge, pandas.excelwriter

Im trying to merge two dataframes df1 and df2 and get only the rows which have same values for 'column1' and write the resultant dataframe to an excel.

Code:

```
#some other code above

if df1.empty == False and df2.empty == False:
    common_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on='column1')
    with pd.ExcelWriter('/usr/outfile.xlsx') as writer:
        common_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='common', index=False)
else:
    pass
```

**While running my code i had 20000 rows in df1 and 300000 rows in df2.**

Few rows of my df1 and df2.

df1:

[image]df2:[image]

If everything went fine i might had some 10000 rows in my common_df and should have written easily to excel sheet. But merge step is returning some huge amount of data which cannot to be written to excel.

ERROR:

```
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 804, in write
    f"This sheet is too large! Your sheet size is: {num_rows}, {num_cols} "
ValueError: This sheet is too large! Your sheet size is: 10325130, 9 Max sheet size is: 1048576, 16384
```

Am i doing anything wrong here? Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a few rows of `df1` and `df2` as an example?

Comment: @not_speshal updated my question with few rows of my dfs, kindly check.

Comment: What does `common_df.shape` return?

Comment: Values of `column1` are unique or can be duplicated?

Comment: @Corralien 'column1' will have few duplicates sometimes